# Issue writing to file(not recognized as readable file) in C

Tags: c, file, output, fwrite

Any idea why it is not printing each char into my output file? When I check my output file is displays this message

"gedit has not been able to detect the character coding.
Please check that you are not trying to open a binary file.
Select a character coding from the menu and try again." with utf-8 encoding

Is this possibly because a bad character or null character was written into the output file?

Because when I checked each char before it is written it is not null and matches the encoding.

```
 void *OUTgroup(void *arg)
 {     
   sleep();

   printf("OUT Thread working\n");
   while(1)
   {
      if(head > tail)
        break;

      if(isEmpty())
        sleep(); 

       BufferItem item = readItem();


       writeFile(item.data, item.offset);

        sleep();
   }

   pthread_exit(0);
 }


void writeFile(char data, off_t offset)
{
   pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);

   /********* CRITICAL SECTION *********/
   if(fseek(file_out, offset, SEEK_SET) == -1)
   {
      printf("Did not successfully find position to output\n");
      exit(0);
   }
   if(fputc(data, file_out) == EOF) 
   {
     printf("Did not successfully write byte to output\n");
     exit(0);
   }
   /********* CRITICAL SECTION *********/
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
}
```

Comment: What is this `sleep` function that you're calling with no arguments?

Comment: What the ... `while (1) { if (head > tail) break; ... }` is it that you like to use `break` even when you don't need it? why don't you just `while (head <= tail)`? And mixing declarations with code is not nice in c, it's necessary in c++ and it's one of the reasons I think c++ code is harder to understand.

Comment: sleep() just makes the thread sleep for 1 - 0.01 seconds

Comment: This isn't a final copy of my code, I am trying to fix a different problem which is output of my file not my loop condition. I left the break statement there because I will later go back and fix it .

Comment: @geforce, it would be wiser to choose function names that do not conflict with library function names.  `sleep()` is a POSIX-standardized function, but the POSIX version take the time to sleep (in seconds) as an argument.

Comment: @geforce, Have you considered looking at the output file in a hex editor to determine what it actually does contain?  That might give you a hint about what's going on.  My guess, though, would be that you never write anything into the file at offset 0 (but do write at higher offsets), so that when you're done, the file starts with one or more null bytes where you never wrote anything.

Comment: I checked the file using a hex editor called Frhed and it shows about 2 letters printed which is 'MI' and the rest it shows dots. What would this mean?

Comment: How would I be able to make sure offset 0 is written in and other ones also?

Answer (score 0):

My first instinct would be that you are not closing your file properly. Try adding a block of code to the end of your execution that both flushes and closes your file descriptor.

```
fflush(file_out);
fclose(file_out);
```